# How to compare values in a pandas pivot table?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm currently analyzing a dataset with Olympic games medalists, `df.head()` is on the image below:

[image]

I am trying to figure out **how many athletes received strictly more Gold medals than Silver and strictly more Silver medals than Bronze**?

I started with creating a pivot table but don't see how to proceed and compare the number of medals against each other for each athlete. This is my code so far:

```
newdf_athletes = df.pivot_table(index = "Athlete", values = "Sport", columns = "Medal", aggfunc = "count")
```

Does it make sense to use a pivot table here at all?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don’t post images of the data as we can’t test them.  Instead, post a sample of the DataFrame and expected output directly inside a code block.  A good way is to share the outputs of `print(df.head().to_dict(orient=‘list’))` along with `print(df.head())`. This allows us to easily reproduce your problem and help you. Read [How to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2):

`pivot_table` might be a way of making it work. Personally I would incline towards `groupby()` via the following code:

```
medals = df.groupby(['Athlete','Medal'])['Event'].count())
```

Pivotting could also work, you can then filter with slicing so that you only keep the athletes which fulfilled the condition:

```
athletes = newdf_athletes[(newdf_athletes['Gold'] > newdf_athletes['Silver']) & (newdf_athletes['Silver'] > newdf_athletes['Bronze'])
```